# Мой скрипт не работает

Tags: javascript, html, eel

Я работаю с библиотекой eel для питона, но пока основной код это js + html
main.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Converter</title>
    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <select name="type">
      <option></option>
      <option value="pp">Промышленные проекты</option>
      <option value="ppp">Потенциально промышленные проекты</option>
      <option value="np">Некоммерческие проекты </option>
    </select>
    <div name="project"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      async function changeOption(){
        if (type.options[type.selectedIndex].value == "pp"){
          project.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<select>
            <option value=\"vr\">В разработке</option>
            <option value=\"ukr\">Утверждённые к разработке</option>
            <option value=\"okr\">Обоснованные к разработке</option>
          </select>");
        } else if(type.options[type.selectedIndex].value == "ppp"){
          project.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<select>
            <option value=\"n\">None</option>
            <option value=\"ro\">Разработка ожидается/задерживается</option>
          </select>");
        }else{
          project.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<select>
            <option value=\"n\">None</option>
            <option value=\"rnv\">Разработка не выяснена/нецелесообразна</option>
          </select>");
        }
      }

      type.addEventListener("change", changeOption);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.py

```
import eel

eel.init("web")

eel.start("main.html", size=(700,700))
```

Как видно, скрипт должен создавать новый тег select в зависимости от того, что выбрано в первом select, но этого не происходит

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А мой - работает.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Converter</title>
    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <select name="type" id="type">
      <option></option>
      <option value="pp">Промышленные проекты</option>
      <option value="ppp">Потенциально промышленные проекты</option>
      <option value="np">Некоммерческие проекты </option>
    </select>
    <div id="project"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const type = document.getElementById("type");
      const project = document.getElementById("project");
      
      function changeOption(){
        if (type.value == "pp"){
          project.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `<select>
            <option value=\"vr\">В разработке</option>
            <option value=\"ukr\">Утверждённые к разработке</option>
            <option value=\"okr\">Обоснованные к разработке</option>
          </select>`);
        } else if(type.value == "ppp"){
          project.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `<select>
            <option value=\"n\">None</option>
            <option value=\"ro\">Разработка ожидается/задерживается</option>
          </select>`);
        }else{
          project.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `<select>
            <option value=\"n\">None</option>
            <option value=\"rnv\">Разработка не выяснена/нецелесообразна</option>
          </select>`);
        }
      }

      type.addEventListener("change", changeOption);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```